# {h-schema} is not taking the default schema while calling the procedure using @Procedure()

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

`{h-schema}` is not taking the default schema while calling the procedure using `@Procedure()` .

**boostrap.yml**

```
spring:
   jpa:
      properties:
         hibernate:
            proc:
               param_null_passing: true
            **default_schema: IDS**
```

**AggregateRepository.java**

```
@Procedure(value = "**{h-schema}**INVOICE_ACTIVITY_DATA.populate_activity_data")
    String loadIdsData(long custId, long buId, long fcyId, String activityCodes);
```

{h-schema} is not taking the default schema given configured in the bootstrap file while calling the procedure but the same is working for tables given in the **@Query()**. I assume {h-schema} is working only for the native queries(i.e, **nativeQuery = true**). Not able to find any alternative solution.

Please help me resolve this issue. Thanks in advance!